# Android Facebook SDK problems with getting selected user with OnSelectionChangeListener

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, adt

Im using the same format as the Facebook SDK samples shows in it's code

```
    friendPickerFragment.setOnSelectionChangedListener(new PickerFragment.OnSelectionChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectionChanged(PickerFragment<?> fragment){
            FriendPickerApplication application = (FriendPickerApplication) getApplication();
            application.setSelectedUser(friendPickerFragment.getSelection());

        }
```

and the method for setSelectedUser on my application code

```
public void setSelectedUser(GraphUser selectedUser) {
    this.selectedUser = selectedUser;
}
```

and defining selectedUser as

```
private GraphUser selectedUser;
```

The problem lies within the application.setSelectedUser
It returns the error "The method setSelectedUser(GraphUser) in the type FriendPickerApplication is not applicable for the arguments (List GraphUser)"

setSelectedUser clearly does not ask for a list. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`friendPickerFragment.getSelection()` returns List.
check [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/FriendPickerFragment#getSelection%28%29)

so try this one.

```
public void setSelectedUser(ListGraphUser selectedUser) {
    this.selectedUser = selectedUser;
}

private ListGraphUser selectedUser;
```